# JQuery Live Search in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I want to make live search using codeigniter and jquery and mysql
but when i type something the result's not showing

**here is my model code :**

```
<?php
class artikel_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function cari_artikel($q)
    {
        $this->db->select('judul,contain');
        $this->db->like('judul', $q);
        $this->db->or_like('contain', $q);
        $query = $this->db->get('artikel');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
?>
```

**and here is my controller code:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('artikel_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['q']) && $_GET['q']){
            $q = $this->input->get('q');
            $this->data['data']=$this->artikel_model->cari_artikel($q);
        }
        else{
            $this->data['data']=array_fill_keys(array('judul', 'contain'), NULL);
        }
        $this->data['body']='dashboard';
        $this->load->view('welcome_message',$this->data);
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

**this is my view code**

```
<?php $this->load->helper('html');?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12 offset3">
            <form class="form-inline" name="form1" method="get" action="">
                Search : <input type="text" class=span5 name="q" id="q"/>   <label for="mySubmit" class="btn  btn-primary"><i class="icon-search icon-white"></i></label> <input id="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Go" class="hidden" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php echo br(15); ?>

    <div id="result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var allow = true;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#q").keypress(function(e){
                if(e.which == '13'){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    loadData();
                }else if($(this).val().length >= 2){
                    loadData();
                }
            });
        });
        function loadData(){
            if(allow){
                allow = false;
                $("#result").html('loading...');
                $.ajax({
                    url:'http://localhost/helpdesk?q='+escape($("#q").val()),
                    success: function (data){
                        $("#result").html(data);
                        allow = true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
<?php
foreach($data as $row){ ?>
    <h3><?php echo $row['judul']; ?></h3>
<?php } ?>
```

The live search is not working.
when i type something the output just "loading..."
and the result is not showing..

If i press enter, the result will show. but that is just the usual searching method. Not live searching.

Comment: echo your last executed query. console it in firebug you can easily find the problem.. use before returning the result ' echo $this->db->last_query(); '

Comment: Your ajax call is invoking the URL `ajax-search.php` which is a separate file and not in your controller. Does this file exist? If it does exist can you please post that too?

Comment: ajax-search.php?q=... this is the bad manners to use
if you calling controller then just pass that controller name/function name.            
var q =$("#q").val();
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "<?=site_url('Welcome')?>",
    data: {q: q},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){alert(data)}

Comment: @user1612290: owh sorry, the right one not `ajax-search.php` but `http://localhost/helpdesk` this is where the controller working..

Comment: I'm going to assume that `http://localhost/helpdesk/` invokes the `index()` function of your `Welcome` controller (if not ignore this). If that is the case do you have anything (a view, etc.) that is printing the HTML to be returned through the AJAX call? It looks like if you run the code now it will pass back a whole new page to be inserted into the `#result` div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a new function say "live_search" that will only return the result with the ajax search and not the "index" function. This new function will return the result with the HTML markup.

```
    public function live_search(){
    if($this->input->post(null)){
       //put your search code here and just "echo" it out 
    }
    }
    $.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost/domain/controller/live_search',
            type : 'POST',
            data : { 'q' : escape($("#q").val()) },
            success: function (data){
                $("#result").html(data);
                allow = true;
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: where i put the function?
view or controller?

Comment: You have to put the function in your controller. Then just echo the result HTML which will be loaded in "#result".